# Create multiple Channels in Microsoft Teams only creates "some" channels

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm using the [Create channel](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_channels) endpoint of the Microsoft Graph to create Channels in my Teams.

When creating multiple Channels in the same Team within a short amount of time (I have a delay of 2s between each call), not all Channels are created.

The API call returns a `201 Created` response for each Channel and, in the General channel, it shows that all my channels are created but they aren't all clickable (and they do not show in the channels overview):

- [Channel creation message in General channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDvi2.png)
- [List of Channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaFWd.png)

Same happens when using the connector in Flow and Logic Apps.

Do I need more delay between calls? Is this a known issue that is not listed on the Know Issues page? Quirks with the beta endpoint I just have to deal with?

EDIT:
As requested:

- TeamId: 6d36a694-22f2-4691-9884-faa2c4517a1f
- TenantId: b868e8f4-7920-4c24-8c95-7f432eba848b
- Request headers (Input1 en Input4 have working Channels): https://gist.github.com/YannickRe/0be8dc213f44c5eb9b33bd31425af219

Additional thing I noticed through Graph Explorer: Get Channels does not show all Channels, but when using [Get Team Channel](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channel_get) and a specific id, all Channels can be found.

EDIT2, more Gists as requested:

- TeamId: 4b915404-d27d-43ee-9ad2-781c6395f059
- TenantId: b868e8f4-7920-4c24-8c95-7f432eba848b
- Headers (input2 and input3 resulted in working channels): https://gist.github.com/YannickRe/a701e2d3cbcba798a23f1fb3ca7439df

Comment: How many channels are you creating and how many are failing? I tried with 4-5 and I could see all the channels.

Comment: I tried creating 4 channels. Sometimes they all succeed, but mostly I see only 1 or 2 succeeding. Couldn't find any pattern: sometimes channel 1 and 3 succeed,  sometimes 1 and 4.

Comment: Could you please share the group id and tenant id from graph explorer for the team?
Does [getChannels](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_list_channels) show the channel at all?
Does restarting the client helps?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I created a different Team, it created 2 out of 4 channels. TeamId: 6d36a694-22f2-4691-9884-faa2c4517a1f & TenantId: b868e8f4-7920-4c24-8c95-7f432eba848b Restarting the client doesn't help, and the getChannel call only shows the same channels as the client.

Comment: We could only see successful request for channel creation in past 10 days. Could you please share response headers and payload for the success and failing channels in the session?

Comment: I would expect them to all show up successful in the log, as they all returned a `201` result. I edited the original post, added link to a gist with input and output. Additional thing I noticed through Graph Explorer: Get Channels does not show all Channels, but when using Get Team Channel and a specific id, all Channels can be found.

Comment: Could you please give it a try one last time and send the request/response same as before?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Done, please see the original message.

Comment: We observed in the traces that in a few cases the post channel calls happened  < 1 sec. Whic is causing a race condition at our end. We are working on fixing this.
 
Meanwhile, as a work-around, could you please increase timeouts between the calls to PostChannel to 5 second and retry?

Comment: I was suspecting something like this, as a workaround I will add more time in between but this will increase the cost of my Logic App so it isn’t acceptable as a long term solution. Will you keep me informed when this is fixed? I think my other open question also deals with a similar race condition on the Teams end of things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237493/microsoft-graph-removal-of-owners-from-group-is-inconsistent-in-microsoft-teams/50238126#50238126